# refresh a view when a parameter of UIViewController change

Tags: swift

I have a page with a TableView. When we tap on a cell it loads a new page. The new page should print an image which depends on the cell we tapped.

Here is my function to load the new page when a cell is tapped :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    
    let vc = ProblemPresentation()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    vc.selectedImage = "problem\(indexPath.row)"
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
```

The problem is that I can't see the image on my new page. I guess it's because when I do `vc.selectedImage = "..."` the vc page has already been loaded and thus I can't see the image on my new page.
Is there a way to make my function works ? Maybe there is something like `vc.refresh` I can do just after the `vc.selectedImage` so that it works.

Here is the code where I load my new page :

```
import UIKit

class ProblemPresentation: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var problemImage: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage: String?
    let sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 545, width: 230, height: 40))
    
    let solution = ["600", "1", "0.5"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        if let notNil = problemImage {
        notNil.image = UIImage(named: selectedImage ?? "Ncorrect")
        notNil.layer.masksToBounds = true
        notNil.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        notNil.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that you aren't showing a thing for your new page.

Comment: @ElTomato I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Question1010 can you please add code for View Controller(your new page) in which you are showing an image?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Yes of course ! You can now see the part of the code where I load my image.

Comment: @Question1010 i think you have to check `selectedImage` variable value not the `problemImage` so try to check if you get `selectedImage` value like this `if let notNil = selectedImage {  problemImage.image = UIImage(named: notNil) } else { problemImage.image = UIImage(named: "Ncorrect") //your default image }` and make sure you are passing correct image name and also image available in project

Comment: @KishanBhatiya the problem is that problemImage is nil, so the line problemImage.image = UIImage(named: notNil) is sendind me an error

Comment: @Question1010 which type of error and have you try with my code?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file I get this because problemImage is nil, so I can't do problemImage.image

Comment: @Question1010 make sure outlet `problemImage` is connected from storyboard or try to reconnect it

Comment: @KishanBhatiya yes it's connected, but even if it's connected it doesn't mean it will not be nil...

Comment: @Question1010 `let vc = ProblemPresentation()` like this not working  because you're creating the controller without giving the storyboard a chance to link the IBOutlets. Instead use `if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourstoryboardId") as? YourcontrollerName {  ...  }` and try to clean and run project

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didSet` to refresh:

```swift
var selectedImage: String? {
    didSet {
        problemImage.image = UIImage(named: selectedImage ?? "Ncorrect")
    }
}
```